# run Google Chome on legacy 7.10 computer?

Tags: google-chrome, 7.10

I managed to install google-chrome on an Ubuntu 7.10 system with `--force-depends`. But now when I try to run it, I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to still get google-chrome to load even without this dependency satisfied?

This is an old system that needs to keep this old 7.10 Ubuntu version installed, meaning that it cannot have a system upgrade because of legacy software that needs to be in the 7.10 system and cannot be installed in any other Linux version. Because of this legacy software that cannot be installed in any other system other than 7.10, what I am trying to achieve is instead try to get google-chrome to work on this 7.10 system. I would like to have google-chrome running if at all possible, even if it means no sound or other features that are not compatible.

Answer (score 2):

You can try running `sudo dpkg -i --force-depends chrome_pkg.deb` to force it to turn dependency errors into warnings.